# How to identify the input shape of a TorchScript model?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, torchscript

I have a file with a model saved as torchscript. I need to run it, but I dont have the information of its input shape. Is there a way to find out by looking at the file?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Netron software to analyze input & output of different nodes.
https://netron.app/